# Foreach Loop File.Readlines displays nothing

Tags: c#, foreach, readlines

I have a foreach loop that is supposed to display lines from a txt file when I click a button.  Nothing is displaying when I click the button.  What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Main(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\AirportCodes2.txt"))
            {
                if (line.Contains("Chicago"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Text file is tab delimited, formatted like this:

Chicago IL  ORD O'Hare International

Comment: Console.WriteLine in a web form?  Does it work in a console app?

Comment: Are you generating an error?  Throw in a try/catch.

Comment: I am attempting to do this in a web form.  Is there a simple way to do this?  I am struggling to find documentation online.

Comment: Also, nowhere in there is a button click handler defined.  WebForms don't do `Main`.  You got some readin' to do.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` is going to write a line to the console; not the page response.  That's what the "Console" part means.

Comment: Change "Main" to "Page_Load" and "Console.WriteLine" to "Response.Write" and you should see something. But you do need to do a bit of research :)

Comment: You're approaching this in an extremely wrong way. You are missing many basic concepts in web applications. I would suggest you drop everything, and find a good ASP.NET tutorial.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Yeah I'm just getting started.

Comment: Try http://www.asp.net. It's a very good resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is web form, hook up Page_Load event of the page. But I recommend to go through ASP.NET page life cycle to understand pre-defined events.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\AirportCodes2.txt"))
     {
         if (line.Contains("Chicago"))
         {
                 Response.Write(line);
         }
     }
}
```

Since it is web application, place the txt file in App_Data folder and access it using Server.MapPath function. Reason being that the path might be different from the local machine and when you finally deploy it to web server.

Import `using System.Text;` namespace

```
 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
 int i = 0;
 foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/AirportCodes2.txt")))
 {
       if (line.Contains("Chicago"))
       { 
           i = i + 1;
           result.Append((string.Format("label{0}:{1}",i,line));
           result.Append("<br/>");
       }
}
lblAirportCodes = result.ToString();
```

**In aspx:**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblAirportCodes"/>
```

Comment: would there be a way to dynamically add the lines to a label?  Label{1}.(line) instead of Response.Write(line);?

Comment: that will add label1:Chicago IL ORD O'Hare International  I meant existing WebControl Labels.  I appreciate your help.